# Failed to handle method call on Local Notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I'm testing out this this plugin for local notifications. This is NotificationService class to handle the plug in

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('flutter_logo.png');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }
}
```

This is very similar to the documentation for the plugin but its not working . when i call showNotification() it shows this

```
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:978)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25530):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```